# Origins of the Twin Prime Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-history

The exciting new results by Zhang and others about bounds on the gaps between pairs of primes have been getting a fair amount of press, which is great! Some of them have gotten me wondering about the origins and history of the Twin Prime Conjecture. My searches into this question have been so far been unsatisfying.

Several articles claim that the conjecture can be attributed to Euclid:

> Some attribute the conjecture to the Greek mathematician Euclid of
>   Alexandria, which would make it one of the oldest open problems in
>   mathematics. (from [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/05/14/twin-primes-conjecture-weak-yitang-zhang_n_3271650.html))

This isn't very satisfying. It's possible that this is true, but to my knowledge Euclid's extant works do not contain such a conjecture, or even conjectures at all. ([overview](http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/euclid.html)) So if this is true, Euclid's claim to of the Twin Primes Conjecture must have come from later sources.

Wikipedia has only the following weak statement to offer:

> The question of whether there exist infinitely many twin primes has
>   been one of the great open questions in number theory for many years. (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime))

My many Google searches have not been successful in getting better information. Can anyone share a trustworthy reference about when the Twin Prime Conjecture was first stated? Bonus points if it gives some of the further history of this conjecture. The Wikipedia article only picks up in the early twentieth century. Thanks!

Comment: Did you come across this one? http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0774.pdf

Comment: @Amzoti, a paper without an author?

Comment: @lhf: Here you go: http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0774

Comment: @Amzoti I did. Searching through it more closely now, I see a reference to de Polignac: "The ﬁrst mention of twin primes in the literature
appears in de Polignac’s paper of 1849, in which he speculates about the
distribution of primes." I've pulled up the reference that's cited, which you can find here: http://libarchive.dartmouth.edu/cdm/compoundobject/collection/dcdis/id/36604/rec/14

Comment: @JustinLanier: yep, I see it and glad you found it - looks like there are some more nuggets in there too, including the references at the end. Regards

Comment: @JustinLanier: You might also want to review http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7639/twin-prime-conjecture-reference

Comment: The Dartmouth paper by Klyve in turn cites de Polignac's original paper of 1849. Since Klyve's paper is his dissertation and it's about twin primes, I'm sure he did an extensive literature before he made the claim that "The first mention of twin primes in the literature appears in de Polignac’s paper of 1849". As an additional reference, there's this page about de Polignac's conjecture at MathWorld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dePolignacsConjecture.html

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks for the MathOverflow link!

Comment: @JustinLanier: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: Note that there's always an issue with judging hold old conjectures are that are very old, because it isn't until modern times that people would generally often explicitly state that they didn't know something, or that they suspected something but couldn't prove it, so trying to date very old conjectures requires often reading between the lines. For example, the oldest explicit question of whether there are any odd perfect numbers is in Descartes, but looking at what older sources are proving, they seem to be thinking about that question.

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment :** I believe that its origins will be forever lost in the mist of time, 
 for the following very simple reason :

Euler was already aware in the eighteenth century that all primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of 
 the form $6n\pm1.~($At any rate, such a **trivial** statement is relatively **easy** to either discover 
 or understand, even by people with only the most **basic** mathematical knowledge$).~$

Then the *next* question which *naturally* arises is about the density of those “lucky” values of 
 *n* for which *both* neighbors of $6n$ are *simultaneously* prime. So basically all that's left to do, 
 after first dispensing with certain *formalities* pertaining to what is considered to be academi– 
 cally acceptable mathematical *etiquette*, such as actually *proving* that their number is *indeed* 
 infinite $($most likely by using some **painfully obvious** argument based, say, on reduction to 
 the absurd, and the like : as in the case of proving that there are an infinite number of primes, 
 for instance$),~$ would be getting down to the **really hard** part of actually quantifying their 
 frequency, and then venturing to offer a mathematical explanation for the experimentally 
 obtained results $\ldots$

Except that —oh, wait a second— remember that first “easy” half we were talking about just 
 earlier ? Well, as “luck” would have it, it turned out to be not so easy after all $\ldots$ So that's it, 
 in a nutshell.

Comment: See also [this essentially identical Question](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/what-is-the-origin-of-the-twin-primes-conjecture) at History of Science and Mathematics, posted in April of 2016.  Given the tenuous nature of conjectures, I suspect the most that can be said with certainty is that Greek writers such as [Thymaridas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymaridas) were concerned with primality before Euclid.